# A collective noun when referring to a group of people with the same name?

Tags: names, grammatical-number

How can I refer collectively to a group of people with the same name, for example:

> Having so many Johns around is confusing.

or

> Having so many John's around is confusing.

Which one is the correct usage? Or should I only refer to them as "people named John"?

This could be somewhat compounded when surnames are used, if the pluralized version is also common.

Comment: Simple rule of thumb: if you want a plural, don't use an apostrophe. Apostrophe-s is for possessives.

Comment: @JPmiaou: A thousand of p's and q's would beg to differ.

Comment: rules of thumb have generally have exceptions.

Comment: Dratted thing won't let me edit my comment; the first 'have' is of course extraneous.

Comment: And "its" is possessive while "it's" is not possessive but instead is the contraction of "it is".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Johns* is fine (if a bit [unfortunate in its implications](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/john) for that particular name).  *John's* means "belonging to John".

Comment: So what about pluralization that changes the spelling? e.g. "I know way to many Shelbies" or "Emilies are always nice people" or "I like all Timothies".

Comment: @medley56: Bad. Shelbys, Emilys, and Timothys.

Answer (score 3):

As evidenced by the common phrase "keeping up with the Joneses", simply pluralizing, even if the name is already theoretically in a plural form, is the way to go.